# Update columns with same value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called "products" with around 500 products and i need to insert in the first 350 products for the description "Sample description" and for the other 150 products "sample 2 description".

How i can do that?

Many thanks!

Code:

```
UPDATE ps_product_lang SET description = CASE WHEN id_product <= 2124 THEN '<div style="line-height:24px;color:#000000;line-height:24px;">' ELSE '<div style="line-height:60px;color:#FFFFFF;line-height:28px;">' END
```

Comment: How do you know which ones were the first ones? Do you have an autoincrement field or insertion date field?

Comment: Are there any gaps in the ids or are they numbered 1,2,...,499,500?

Comment: Would does it work using LIMIT? (It'd works also with gaps in the ids)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the first 350 products have ids from 1 to 350, you can try this:

```
UPDATE products
SET description = CASE
    WHEN id <= 350 THEN 'Sample description'
    ELSE 'sample description 2'
END
```

Comment: But what is when the value is  <div style="line-height:24px;color:#000000;line-height:24px;"> ? I get a error.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'none') { document.getElementById(id).style.display='block'; } else ' at line 4

Comment: @PhillipSchneider: You aren't correctly escaping your strings. You'll have to post all the relevant code if you want more specific advice on how to fix it, but you could start by looking [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: @PhillipSchneider: I don't see how that code could possibly generate the error message you claim it does. The error message says `near 'none')` but your code does not even contain the word `none`. Perhaps you posted the wrong code?

Comment: Sorry the first line was not correct. I have there a ' character. How i can make the update if in my values are '

Comment: @PhillipSchneider: When you have a single quote inside a single quoted string you should replace it with two single quotes, or a backslash followed by a single quote. If you don't do this, the string will terminate early and the rest of the string will be interpreted as (usually invalid) SQL. If you want more details you should create a new question as the comments aren't really a suitable place for this sort of discussion.

Comment: Can you please post me a example. Becouse i dont understand it :( ... my english is to bad.

Comment: @PhillipSchneider: I'm sorry but I'm not interested in having long discussions in comments. Either modify your question so that it asks for the information you want to know, or post a new question.